# How strong would graphene armour be? What is the best design?

Tags: technology, military

For quite some time I wondered how strong graphene is as armour.  Don’t get me wrong, I understand what graphenes is and would no doubt make excellent armour.

I want to know how good it would be and what design of armour is the best with this wonder material.

Would a spaced design work better or just having multiple stacks of graphene layered onto each other? Let’s assume armour for a solider in the field.  No concealed and armoured jackets for now.

Comment: It'd be 2x as good as nowadays vests: https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn26626-bulletproof-graphene-makes-ultra-strong-body-armour/

Comment: While it's not graphene, just carbon-fiber, a reference point could be [this armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Weapons_Master). In short, while it can only stop low-energy firearms, it can absorb melee weapon blows so much better, powerful firearms with AP bullets are still the way to go to defeating it. It wasn't designed to stop bullets, though.

Comment: @Renan Actually, it's only twice as good if you use single-layer graphene, so probably for some more complex structure it would be even better. Or maybe not.

Comment: You're asking two questions here... one about graphene armour, and the other about what happens to warfare when armour is better than (current) guns. I'd split them up if I were you; this plave works much better when you ask one quiestion at a time.

Comment: I agree with Starfish. Remove the second question to another post! That follows best practice for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @daniel After consulting with other moderators, I removed the extra question from your post. Focusing on just one question will get you better answers. Feel free to post your second question later as a follow up, after this one gets answered. "How is warfare affected when the armour has (temporally) out paced guns.  How can guns compete?" ... but I suspect there are several questions already on the forum with good answers to this specific point. You may want to search a bit before posting. WELCOME TO WORLDBUILDING! :-)

Comment: Good to know in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: When you've reposted the other half of the question, I'll see about throwing an answer together ;-) As for this one though, it seems an awful lot like "nobody knows", because we don't have bulk graphene synthesis yet. Renan's link seems like it is probably as good an answer as you're likely to get any time soon. But hey, it means you can handwave some properties and it'll be years before anyone can tell you that you're wrong, and maybe you'll turn out to be right after all and seem like a visionary.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to take a look at aggregated diamond nanorod. As far as I know it’s the hardest material we have and would probably pair quite nicely as an outer layer for graphine armor. Also, if you can roll graphine into tubes you get carbon nanotubes, another super material! Otherwise I’d have to agree with the above, we don’t really have mass production of graphine so we kind of have to guess at how exactly it would behave.

Comment: Again I agree with @StarfishPrime ... some cursory searches with the usual data sources didn't turn up any info on impact resistance of graphene beyond what you can find in a trivial web search. Sorry... I think this question will just have to hang open for a few years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tricky thing about graphene is that it is really, really, thin. It only takes a few sheets of graphene to out-perform a kevlar vest, but you could in theory make it a million or even a billion layers thick, and still make a quite comfortably thin and light weight armor material.  In other words, you can make it as much stronger than modern armor as you want as long as you are willing to spend the time and money making it that thick.

The real limitation is how much force can be transferred through it.  Once you get past a certain thickness, the graphene will hold up against almost anything, but the person inside will be turned into blood pudding from the impact force.  This means that the best design will be to layer the graphene over whatever distributes the impact the best. Currently non-newtonian fluids offer the best impact distribution for their weight.

In short, you are looking at what modern body armor already looks like, just with a hundred or so layers of graphene to reinforce it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the graphene plating would be replacing the ceramic stuff?

Comment: You need to add some layer with non newtonian fluids to absorb the energy and distribute it. Otherwise you get a cracked rib. You can buy shock absorber inlays for common armor.

Comment: @Gio graphene has incredible tensile strength making it very hard to penetrate, but it is not ridgid.  Think of it more like a super thin cloth  To distribute the impact, you need something ridgid under it like a ceramic plate or a non-newtonian fluid as Gustavo suggests. Otherwise, the graphene will conically deform and penetrate into you around the bullet.  The bullet would not pierce the graphene, but it may not need to to be able to kill you.

Answer (score 2):

According to furturism.com, you would only need two layers of graphene to create an armor that was as hard as diamond (and can block bullets).

https://futurism.com/two-layers-graphene-make-diamond-hard-armor-stop-bullet

This article talks about some experimentation scientists have been doing on graphene layers. (They have also found out it is is a lot more effective than kevlar)

https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/195089-graphene-body-armor-twice-the-stopping-power-of-kevlar-at-a-fraction-of-the-weight